# Complex Cauchy's integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

i am currently going through a course about complex functions. when i was solving some home exercises about the Cauchy's integral theorem, i noticed something i just cant find the answer to.

It goes like this:

It is easy to see that the answer to the following integral is like so:
Using Cauchy's integral theorem

$\int \frac{e^{z}}zdz = 2i\pi\ $  - through any rectifiable path

If i change parameters and say that

$ z=e^{i\theta} $ so that,

$dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$

And now i replace the parameters inside the integral so i get

$\int \frac{e^{z}}zdz = \int \frac{e^{e^{i\theta}}}{e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}d\theta = 2i\pi\ $

i can now cancel the $ e^{i\theta} $

$\int {e^{e^{i\theta}}}id\theta = 2i\pi\ $

Now i can divide by $i$ on both sides and i get the final result:

$\int {e^{e^{i\theta}}}d\theta = 2\pi\ $

So, my question is how suddenly the result of the integral became a Real number.
when first it was clearly a Complex number.
Was there something wrong in the process of the parameter replacement or there is some deeper explanation to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you expect? You have divided by $i$! Yes, the original integral is $\int_\gamma\frac{e^{iz}}z\,\mathrm dz$, which, yes, is equal to $2\pi i$. But after dividing by $i$ what you get is$$\frac1i\int_\gamma\frac{e^{iz}}z\,\mathrm dz=2\pi,$$and $2\pi$ is a real number.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Its funny how the most obvious and logic reason is the right answer and i missed it. Thank you for the quick reply. Have a great day!